Good Resources to understand the construction of Real Numbers
I am learning for an exam, but I am a very picky person and don't consider myself knowledgeable about a topic unless I understand everything to the fullest, which is never really possible. But I am dissatisfied that we did not construct the real numbers in my real analysis course so I wanted to look at some good resources.
I found this document Reals it is of the utah university. Are there good resources you can recommend for me to look at?
Thank you for your help!
Edit:
I will keep this threat open for a while because I think I want to read the resources first that you guys provided/provide.
If I remember I will write a summary of the books that helped me the best and close it but if this is considered the wrong thing to do on this forum I will ofc close this thread before. Thanks for all the help already and for every thing that will come. I really apricate the fast responses and I hope I can build a brood perceptive of the topics I want to learn.

Someone, maybe Dedekind, said God gave man the integers, and he did the rest... or something to that effect.   Any way,  Dedekind's "cuts" are worth looking up.

@pontiuspilate I think this is usually credited to Leopold Kronecker.

You're right,  I just looked it up.  @nico. Anyway I think they both contributed to the subject.

Stop answering in the comments, please.

Here are a couple of book suggestions, with somewhat different approaches to the subject:

Michael Henle, Which Numbers are Real?
This book describes the axiomatic approach to real numbers, as well as both Cantor's and Dedekind's constructions of them, and then it compares the real numbers to a bunch of other more exotic number systems (complex numbers, quaternions, constructive reals, hyperreals, surreals).

John Stillwell, The Real Numbers: An Introduction to Set Theory and Analysis
This one stays within the classical world of real numbers, and explains Dedekind's construction. But it also aims to show what one can do with the real numbers, so in addition it contains some set theory, topology and measure theory.



I get the feeling that you read both. Would you recommend starting with John Stilwell and than going to the book of Michael Henle?

I can't tell. I depends on what you're interested in, really.

Stephen Krantz's Real Analysis and Foundations (2ed) goes through this in the Appendix of Chapter 2.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
